# Get All Active Service Instances on Service Start

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-discovery

I'm creating a stateless service inside Azure Service Fabric. However, once service starts (or on start of custom communication listener) I need to get addresses of all other instances/partitions of that service.

I'm doing so by creating new `FabricClient` and calling `fabricClient.QueryManager.GetPartitionListAsync(serviceUri)`. However I'm getting `FabricServiceNotFoundException` with message *Service does not exist.* when a first service instance starts running.

I couldn't find that in documentation, so my question is: how can I get a list of listening endpoint addresses for all active instances of a particular service, running in Azure Service Fabric, when a new instance of that service starts running?

Answer (score 5):

Endpoint addresses are actually on service replicas and instances - those are the things that are actually placed on nodes. There is a special method for this in the [ServiceManagerClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.fabric.fabricclient.servicemanager.aspx) called [ResolveServicePartitionAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.fabric.fabricclient.servicemanagementclient.resolveservicepartitionasync.aspx).

In the Reliable Services SDK (in the Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Client namespace) we provide a resolver utility that makes this a bit easier:

```
ServicePartitionResolver resolver = ServicePartitionResolver.GetDefault();

ResolvedServicePartition partition =
    await resolver.ResolveAsync(new Uri("fabric:/MyApp/MyService"), new ServicePartitionKey(), cancellationToken);
```

The Endpoints property of ResolvedServicePartition is a list of each replica/instance in the partition. The Address property will contain a JSON object, which is a list of key-value pairs containing each listener that's opened by the replica/instance:

```
{
  "Endpoints" :
      { "mylistener1" : "some-address" },
      { "mylistener2" : "some-address" }
      ...
}
```

Keep in mind that there's no guaranteed order for when replicas/instances come up, so you may need to retry a few times. Also, replicas and instances will move at times throughout the service's lifetime, so you'll need to keep the list up to date. Basically you can't really just get all this information up front in one go and be set because it's a very dynamic system.

See here for an overview:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services/

And here for more detailed information: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication/

Comment: Sorry, but your solution also ends up with `System.Fabric.FabricServiceNotFoundException`: *Service does not exist* message. I guess it's the way service fabric is working.

Comment: At what point in your service's lifecycle are you trying to get the addresses of each instance or replica?

Comment: This info is not to be found anywhere else in the interwebs...Thanks

Comment: What would be the best way to serialize that odd Endpoints json syntax?  All the linters and parsers I've tried have failed to validate that json.  If the endpoints is a list, it really should have square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to commenting on StackOverflow but here is how I did my service resolution. I ended up making a small library to take care of it.

```
ResolvedServicePartition partition = await fabricClient.ServiceManager.ResolveServicePartitionAsync("fabric:/Application1/Service1");

// This "endpoint" looks something like this: {\"Endpoints\":{\"\":\"http:\/\/localhost:8448\/\"}}
string randomConfigStoreEndpointJson = partition.GetEndpoint().Address;

// Use Newtonsoft.Json to parse this mess, since JavaScriptSerializer isn't up to the job
JObject endpointObject = JObject.Parse(randomConfigStoreEndpointJson);

// This is the only way I could actually extract the baseUrl without regular expressions
string actualEndpointBaseUrl = endpointObject["Endpoints"].First.First.ToString();
```

@DannyMeister This takes care of parsing that odd endpoint JSON syntax.

This also works to resolve a stateful service with only one partition. To resolve a stateful service with multiple partitions, you must figure out the partitionKey on the client, then call `await fabricClient.ServiceManager.ResolveServicePartitionAsync("fabric:/Application1/Service1", statefulPartitionKey);` instead!