# How to communicate with a specific instance of a stateless service?

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

Is it possible to communicate with a specific instance of a Service Fabric Stateless Service. The partition count for the service is set to '-1' so there should be an instance of that service on each node. I would like to access each of those specifically.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'm curious why you're asking it :)

Comment: I use a stateless service to read from an Service Bus Event Hub and I would like to be able to query each instance for the status of the readers, rather than having them report up every so often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480872/how-can-i-reach-a-specific-replica-of-a-stateless-service/37555012#37555012) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036140/get-all-active-service-instances-on-service-start/38065283#38065283)

tl;dr: Yes you can, but if you need to, you should ask yourself if your service should really be stateful.